# How to undelete a moved file on Linux

Tags: linux, hdparm, undelete

I accidentally moved a file onto an existing file and need to recover the old file.

original file: `/mnt/FILE` (was around 1 GB)

new file: `/mnt/FILE` (now is 17 bytes)

command:

```
mv SOMEFILE /mnt/FILE
```

First I have unmounted the filesystem the file resides on, i.e.

```
umount /mnt
```

Ran a `hdparm --fibmap` on the updated `/mnt/FILE` to get the following:

```
 filesystem blocksize 4096, begins at LBA 0; assuming 512 byte sectors.
 byte_offset  begin_LBA    end_LBA    sectors
           0  342898376  342898383          8
```

I am trying to run a dd on the device where `/mnt/FILE` is (`/dev/xvdb`) to copy out the blocks from the larger file:

```
dd if=/dev/xvdb of=/tmp/FILE bs=4096 skip=342898376 count=1000000000 iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes
```

I don't seem to be getting the right blocks, could you please advise me how to do so.

Comment: You restore from your backup.

Answer (score 2):

What is the filesystem ?

If it's `ext3` (with journaling enabled) or `ext4`, you can try [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/).

I also don't understand your data attempt recovery. Why do you try to recover the first GB from the partition ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is ext4. I could be mistaken but the skip parameter is an offset to start from, i.e. 1gb from there.

Comment: Yes, you are reading 1GB from the beginning of the partition. `xvdb` is the device, and `342898376` is the partition. If it's ext4, **don't keep it mounted in read-write** (or dump it to a safe place), and use extundelete (`photorec` could also help if it's a known file format).

Comment: What is the format of the original file ?

Comment: Try `photorec` !